# According to the C standard, may macros with arguments collide with identifiers?

Tags: c

I think it's better illustrated with an example. With a struct like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    char b;
} Foo;
```

Define a macro:

```
#define Foo(A, B) (Foo){ A, B }
```

Which can then be used like this:

```
Foo foo;
foo = Foo(1, 'c');
```

I've been using this pattern for a while, and for me it's a very elegant way of initializing structs. It works in GCC and Clang (and TCC I think), but in some lesser-known C compilers (like Plan 9's C compiler) it doesn't.

What does the C standard dictates about that topic?

Comment: You don't need `(Foo)` in the expansion, for two reasons: (1) it's not followed by `(` so it won't match a function-like macro; (2) inside the expansion of mla macro `X`, the token `X` is not replaced.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Excerpt from §6.10.3.10 of the C11 standard:

> Each subsequent instance of the function-like macro name **followed by a**
>   **( as the next preprocessing token** introduces the sequence of
>   preprocessing tokens that is replaced by the replacement list in the
>   definition (an invocation of the macro).

So, no, you should not worry. A function-like macro is only replaced if the macro name is followed by an opening parenthesis (.

Comment: Whether it's a good idea to exploit this, on the other hand, is questionable.

Comment: The C standard itself exploits this, as it explicitly grants implementations permission to implement standard library functions as macros in addition to functions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That's a good point, I forgot about `<tgmath.h>` for example.

Answer (score 2):

The preprocessor does text substitution, it doesn't know anything about the C language. Thus, it doesn't care about C identifiers.

So, no, a macros cannot collide with an identifier.

Comment: The preprocessing is a part of the C language (C 2011 clause 6.10 and more) and does have interactions with other parts of the language. The source file is decomposed into preprocessing tokens (5.1.1.2 4), not mere text, and the preprocessor does some arithmetic, not just text substitution, and that arithmetic is governed by the C standard.